# Rails Froala Editor in nested activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, activeadmin, froala

i have some issues with activeadmin_froala_editor gem.

In my form, i can user froala editors, it's working, but in nested forms, it's dont working, but i don't understand why.

This is a part of my code :

```
   form do |f|
        f.inputs "En-tête" do
          f.input :title
          f.input :content, as: :froala_editor
          f.input :banner
        end

        f.inputs "Prix" do
          f.has_many :rewards do |price|
            price.input :name
            price.input :picto
            price.input :description, as: :froala_editor
            price.input :quantity
        end
     end
   end
```

The first froala is working perfectly, but the second one don't appear.

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem "activeadmin_froala_editor" need to be updated

```
$>bundle update activeadmin_froala_editor
```

Be also sure that the version is updated in gemfile.lock.
If you are in early development stade you can erase it.

```
$> rm Gemfile.lock
$> bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra rewards subforms are added dynamically to the page. To have multiple instances of froala_editor on one page, the elements will need to have unique hooks (see https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/inline-two-instances) and you will have to attach the editor yourself through javascript. This is tricky but possible. However, you could at the sacrifice of UX do the following:

Remove the description field from the form, and setup a show block like so:

```
show do |en_tete|
  attributes_table do
    row :title
    row :content
    row :banner
    row :rewards do        
      en_tete.rewards.each do |reward|
        h4 { reward.name }
        span { reward.picto }
        span { reward.quantity }
        div { reward.description.html_safe }
        br
        # use rake routes to find the correct path helper
        a(href: edit_admin_reward_path(reward) { "edit" } 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You will have to register the Reward model in ActiveAdmin, which you could do like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Reward do
  belongs_to :en_tete, :parent_class => "EnTete", :optional => true

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :picto
      f.input :description, as: :froala_editor
      f.input :quantity
    end
    f.actions do
      f.action :submit          
      f.cancel_link(admin_en_tete_path(f.object.en_tete))
    end
  end

  # if you wish you could add this
  controller do
    def show
      redirect_to admin_en_tete_path(resource)
    end
  end

end
```